# How to avoid unnecessary re-rendering of RecyclerView when using Flowable (RxJava)?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java, android-room

Trying to implement MVVM with room flowable @ rxjava + retrofit2.

When the activity starts, I request a list of items from the repository. The repository retrieves them from the database (room) and returns Flowable to the ViewModel. At the same moment, the repository requests the current list from the API, and as soon as the result is returned, I delete the existing entries in the database and insert what arrived from the API.

The observer in activity, of course, updates recyclerview three times. Because of this, ui "blinks" when updating the list:
the list is not empty -> the list is empty -> the list is not empty.

After receiving the flowable from Room for the first time, the observer then receives an empty list (when deleting entries in the database) and then a new list after inserting it into the database from API.

How to avoid this behavior of RecyclerView? Is there any well-established best practice, true way, etc.?

**PaymentRepository method for retrieving payment list:**

```
private Flowable<List<Payment>> getPayments(Long accountId) {
    // requesting actual data from API
    paymentService.getPayments().flatMapCompletable(payments -> paymentDao
            .deleteAllByAccountId(accountId)
            .andThen(paymentDao.insert(payments))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    ).subscribe();

    // and return cached list from db
    return paymentDao.findPaidByAccountId(accountId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
private CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
public MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Payment>>> result = new MutableLiveData<>(Resource.loading());

public PaymentListViewModel() {
    disposable.add(
            paymentRepository.getPayments().subscribe(
                    payments -> result.setValue(Resource.success(payments)),
                    throwable -> result.setValue(paymentService.parseError(throwable).toResource())
            )
    );
}
```

**Observer in Activity**

```
viewModel.result.observe(this, resource -> {
    switch (resource.status) {
        case SUCCESS:
            adapter.setItems(resource.data);
            binding.preloader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case ERROR:
            Toast.makeText(this, resource.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            binding.preloader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case LOADING:
            binding.preloader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use `DiffUtil` class for that https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Room expert, maybe there is so RX-way to update values without emitting it into listeners. 
But here is the way that doesn't request it:

```
private Flowable<List<Payment>> getPayments(Long accountId) {
    // requesting actual data from API
    Flowable<List<Payment>> request = paymentService.getPayments()
            .flatMapCompletable(payments -> paymentDao
                .deleteAllByAccountId(accountId)
                .andThen(paymentDao.insert(payments))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    );

    return paymentDao.findPaidByAccountId(accountId)
            .take(1)
            .switchMap(dbList -> request.startWith(dbList))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .distinctUntilChanged();
}
```

in this scenario you take only first value from DB (`take(1)`) and then wait for the values from API.

`switchMap` (also could be `flatMap` here, no diff in **this** case) guaranty you that DB value will be first and only after that "listen" for API.

The only problem here if you suppose to update DB values somewhere else, while this Activity is running. In that case this updates will not be displayed.